# A MiKTeX update removed amsmath as obsolete – can I use another package or get it back?

Tags: packages, amsmath, miktex, updating, obsolete

I have a problem with `amsmath` package. After an update this package was removed because it was obsolete. But what package can use instead of `amsmath`?

Comment: I updated MikTeX 2.9 today and `amsmath` is still there. Another `ams` package was removed though, with the mention 'obsolete', as you say, but I really don't remember which... `:/`

Comment: Can you provide more details of the update? How did you perform it- using the appropriate package manager as in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) ?

Comment: Hmmmm... I checked package manager and updater. After update was some problem with file (no premission to write or something in C:\Users\Jablon\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\data\le fokder). I have restarted my machine and i deleted this. It works now :) It was some M$ problem probably. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 51):

MiKTeX has reorganized the package `amslatex`. Therefore the update removes it:

> [image: Package update list]

The package `amslatex` is split in `amsmath` and `amscls`. (Also there is a new package `amslatex-primer`):

> [image: "ams" packages in MiKTeX]

However, the update has not installed the new packages automatically. Therefore I have installed them manually. For AmSLaTeX you need at least `amsmath`. It contains the package file `amsmath.sty`. `amscls` contains the AMS classes (`amsbook.cls`, …).

> [image: "ams" packages all installed]

Finally the local repository database is synchronized by calling the MiKTeX Package Manager, menu item `Repository`→`Synchronize`, see comment of Ulrike Fischer.

Comment: When miktex rearranges packages one should synchronize the local repository database to get it up to date. The command is in "Repository" menu of the package manager. After the synchronization miktex will reinstall the files on-the-fly when you try to use them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. It eludes me, why the synchronization is not already done by the update in the first place.

Comment: Probably to save time and bandwidth. Normally everything works fine even without synchronization.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer When `miktex-etex-base-2,9` (iirc) was renamed to `miktex-etex-base-2.9` and I tried "Update Formats", I got an error. So even if running `pdflatex` over some document and then installing packages on the fly was a solution in principle, the current way MiKTeX is implemented is not stable in the sense of it not having prevented this error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I *was* at some point prompted to reinstall something (I think it was `miktex-etex-base-2,9`, but it's been a while) on the fly, and it might even have been the "Update Formats" process which did this immediately after the error (I forgot whether it was so), but only after I figured out to manually add `miktex-etex-base-2.9` (with a period) via the package manager, everything started to work seamlessly again.

Answer (score 29):

`amsmath` is definitely *not* obsolete!  It may have some old and unrepaired bugs, but it still has the status "maintained" and AMS has every intention of keeping it that way.

Something else must have gone wrong with your update.

**EDIT:** `amsmath` and the AMS document classes + `amsthm` used to be combined on CTAN under the name `amslatex`.  They have always been separate in TeX Live, and, although originally bundled together on the AMS server, were repackaged in mid-2010 to be distributed in two parts.

This split was implemented in late January on CTAN, concurrent with a minor update (version 2.14) "to provide more fluid interoperability with stix.sty.  It should be fully compatible with version 2.13."

The consequences of this change (and the ensuing confusion) eluded me when i first answered this question, a fact for which i apologize.

Comment: Shouldn't this answer be "uppercased"? ;-)

Comment: @egreg -- hmmmmph.  it's after quitting time.  (okay, i did it anyhow.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mathtools` instead (you should it instead of `amsmath` because it fixes a bug).

Comment: `mathtools` requires `amsmath` so this wouldn't work if `amsmath` were missing!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem today. 
I ran the update a second time, and that eliminated the error message.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: In my case amsmath was already installed. Updating miktex solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

After manually installing package `amsmath`, `amscls` and `amslatex-primer`, you might have an error about `etex.sty not found`.

You can fix it by using "Package Manager (Admin)" from MiKTeX 2.9.

Choose Repository > Synchronize