# Problem with Miktex installation

Tags: errors, installing, miktex

my miktex distribution has started playing up!  Everything compiled yesterday, but after an automatic update, it has started to do funny things.  It doesn't seem to be able to find the amsmath package in the tree.  I have tried to manually put the style files in the required spot, but when I refresh the FNDB, I get the following message:
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: Windows API error 87: The parameter is incorrect.

Data: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\be48a8a88e3570f31e8be8fd4a43a2fd.fndb

Does anyone know what has happend and the least painful way to fix it?

Thanks,
Brett

Comment: Have a look at: [A MiKTeX update removed amsmath as obsolete – can I use another package or get it back?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96778/amsmath-obsolete-package-which-is-current). Please tell us if it helped. We could close this question as a duplicate then.

Comment: Synchronize the repository (package manager, menu "Repository"). Do it in admin mode + user mode.