# How to check tikz version using \listfiles Command

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I tried to the following code to get the version information about TikZ using `\listfiles` command. However, there is an error says `File amsmath.sty not Found`, may someone help me?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dateiliste}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\printFileList
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `mathtools` package loads `amsmath` by default. Do you use MikTeX? [A MiKTeX update removed amsmath as obsolete – can I use another package or get it back?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96778)

Comment: I fail to see the relevance to `TikZ` in this question? (especially the tag tikz-trees?). If you want information about the tikzversion, use `\pgfversion`. Even though the package `dateiliste` refers `TikZ` your question is about `TikZ`, not `dateiliste`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel yes

Comment: @sweetyBaby Besides the `amsmath` part, you actually need to load TikZ in order to check its version (regardless of the method).

Answer (score 9):

Qrrbrbbirlbel (phew) answered the amsmath update problem. You can read more from Heiko Oberdiek's answer in [A MiKTeX update removed amsmath as obsolete – can I use another package or get it back?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96778)

You can also check your PGF/TikZ version via two options

1. Putting `\listfiles` command in your preamble and reading your log file
2. Or putting `\pgfversion` command somewhere in the document to be printed.

Here is two examples combined

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\pgfversion
\end{document}
```

It gives

[image]

in the resulting PDF file and also in the log file

[image]