# Create tables with pgfplotstable, problem with pgfkeys

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am trying to reproduce this MWE, but I keep getting

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key
>   '/pgfplots/table/copy/column from table' and I am going to ignore it.
>   Perhaps you misspelled it.

seems like this very same code works for some others but for me not. I am using Mac computer and compile the `.tex` file with Texmaker 4.5, anyone knows what is going on??

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{h1_error.log}\dataA    
\pgfplotstableread{l2_error.log}\dataB

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\dataB}{[index]0}] {par1} {\dataA}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\dataB}{[index]1}] {par2} {\dataA}

\pgfplotstabletypeset{\dataA}
\end{document}
```

where 
`h1_error.log` is

```
#N       H1 error
40  0.231438
#N       H1 error
40  -nan
#N       H1 error
40  0.231438
#N       H1 error
5   1.32218
#N       H1 error
5   1.60331
```

and `l2_error.log` is

```
#N       L2 error
40  0.00624957
#N       L2 error
40  0.00809222
#N       L2 error
40  0.00624957
#N       L2 error
5   0.246561
#N       L2 error
5   0.307461
```

Comment: Your MWE perfectly works for me, too. To check the different versions of package you use, with respect to others, put `\listfiles` at the beginning of your .tex file and you'll see the package versions on the log, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97924/how-to-check-tikz-version-using-listfiles-command, for example.