# Still showing the file is missing after installing the package of MikTeX

Tags: installing, miktex

I meet the problem that when running the code, WinEdt says:

> `The required **** file is missing....`

after updating MiKTeX 2.8 to 2.9 version. And I have tried to install the package that missing files in by Package Manager, however, after installing successfully, I still meet the same problem says the same file is missing. Can someone help me?

Comment: There is currently a severe bug in the miktex-runtime-bin. The only known way to get around it (until it has been corrected) is to install only the basic version of miktex (which contains an older version) (And naturally not to update this package). It is also possible to get around the problem by replacing `miktex209-core.dll` with an older version. Perhaps you can find it in a repository which has some delay. http://www.miktex.org/pkg/repositories

Comment: I have an old copy of the file you mention and...it works. Anybody needs it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I updated miktex-runtime-bin and miktex-bin today. Some of my tex-files cannot be compiled anymore; there are suddenly hundreds of error messages. Replacing `miktex209-core.dll` with an older version does not help. Are there any other files I have to replace? I am asking because I want to avoid a new installation of my miktex version.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You get the error also if you update your settings, happened to me the other day...

Comment: @partial: The number of errors doesn't matter, only the content of the first one. It could be that your formats are faulty (that was one of the side effects of the bug, pdflatex suddently made a dvi), recreate the formats in miktex settings. Addition: I saw in the miktex sources that Christian has made some changes about 1,5 hours ago. So I'm quite confident that there will be an update soon.

Comment: The story is that MikTeX updates are too often buggy in recent years. Apart of the evident problem with updated binaries which don't want to see installed packages, the MikTeX update wizard announces that `amsmath` package is obsolete and *must* be removed. Please, don't believe in that.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov See this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96778/16967) for the issue with `amsmath`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I encountered after updating this morning are caused by the file 
`MiKTeX209-core.dll`.

I have an old copy (not updated) which I posted on my website:

http://www.statistica.unimib.it/utenti/cassese/MiKTeX209-core.dll

It is enough to copy it and paste it and that fixes the bug. At least it did for me

Comment: @PeterJansson which is not available for a new user. **gcass:** Since you cannot post comments yet, moderator will convert these to comments. This answer actually looks that you try to answer the question, but it is not clear. If the link you provide should really solve the problem, please explain better what is it about ;)

Comment: @gcass Where did you drop it?

Comment: Having in mind often problems with miktex updates in recent years I never apply updates just after they appear. Unfortunately, I was not so cautious this time. But I have managed to reinstall MikTeX from my local repository. `basic-miktex-2.9.4757.exe` and `basic-miktex-2.9.4757-x64.exe` from `FTP: @tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/setup` could also help.