# amsmath.sty not found

Tags: errors

I have been using LaTeX for a long time now. It has suddenly stopped working:

> `amsmath.sty not found`

I downloaded that and similar files to the same directory. Now it gives the error

> `begin{document}  not found`

But the files are there!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  This problem is probably due to some other error, so it would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem for you.

Comment: If you use MiKTeX, your problem may be explained in the following post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96778/19384

Comment: If nothing else works, you can always make a new installation, but this is og course as a last resource.

Comment: If you use TeX Live, does `kpsewhere amsmath.sty` in a terminal window print out the path to amsmath.sty?
A MWE of your code would be nice to find out, if there's another source for this error message.