# Could not compile pdf after updated

Tags: errors, pdftex, miktex

I have updated my MiKTeX to 2.9. But unfortunately it cannot compile pdf file by either PdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

When use XeLaTeX it lag at the begining, and for PdfLaTeX it returns errors:

```
Command Line:   D:\CTEX\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\latex.exe --src --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "asd.tex"
Startup Folder: E:\temp\exersice

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(E:\temp\exersice\asd.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, ... loaded.
(D:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\size10.clo))latex.exe: GUI framework cannot be initialized.

LaTeX failed to create a dvi file.
For possible explanations start the command from the Command Prompt...
```

My article is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
 $$\mathfrak{A}$$
\end{document}
```

It is sound. So I think there must be some thing wrong with the config but I cannot find any.

Comment: Something is blocking the on the fly installation. (It is probably trying to install amsmath). Open the package manager, synchronize the repository (could be necessary as amsmath has change the location) and then try to install amsmath.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- `amsmath` doesn't provide `\mathfrak`; that requires `\usepackage{amsfonts}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: This error doesn't matter in this case. The compilation fails before (because of the `GUI framework cannot be initialized`)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- agreed, which is why that was a comment, not an answer.  however, since `amsmath` is part of "latex required", it's not clear to me why it needs to be installed on the fly; it should already be present in any normal installation.

Comment: MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: Windows API error 32: ...
Data: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/data/le\c87952ef9592d6b83e569dc28fd7d1f5.fndb
...
Root0: C:\Users\think\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\think\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: D:\CTEX\UserData
Root4: D:\CTEX\MiKTeX
UserInstall: C:\Users\think\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\think\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\think\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: D:\CTEX\MiKTeX
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9

Comment: @barbarabeeton: The amsmath-packages have been reordered. And so at updates miktex removes the old package. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96778/a-miktex-update-removed-amsmath-as-obsolete-can-i-use-another-package-or-get-i

Comment: do the answers to this question -- [A MiKTeX update removed amsmath as obsolete – can I use another package or get it back?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96778/) -- answer the present question?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I synchronized packages, but get a trouble in refresh the fndb... The error messages is shown upper.

Comment: I have used amssymb instead and it works. Thank you very much.