# Undefined control sequence. \pgfplots@already@computed@legend@node

Tags: pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I got following error in my computer only.

```
Undefined control sequence.
\pgfplots@already@computed@legend@node ..._{\text 
                                                  {des}}$};\\\pgfplots@show@...
l.261 \end{axis}
```

here is the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0, xmax=20,
xlabel={Time (s)},
ymin=-10, ymax=10,
ylabel={Angle (deg)},
name=plot2,
title={(b)},
legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
]
\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
line width=1.0pt
]
table{
0 -5
 .
 .
20 -5
};
\addlegendentry{$\theta{}_{\text{des}}$};
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. What is your preamble? Which packages do you load? In which order? By the way, you can use Ctrl+K or the `{ }` button to format code as a code block. Using ` works for inline code.

Comment: The undefined command is the _last_ one on the first line of the message which is `\text` that is defined in the `amsmath` (and `amstext`) package.

Comment: I think you are on MikTeX and updated it. So this might have happened. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96778/3235

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I think problem is with amsmath. I have not checked whether my miktex contains, latest version of amsmath