# Installing amsthm.sty under MiKTeX

Tags: packages, installing, miktex, amsthm

On the LaTeX wikibooks I saw that there is an easy way to make theorems: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems

The problem is that `\usepackage{amsthm}` doesn't work - `asmthm.sty` is not found. And scanning the MiKTeX Package Manager, surely, I didn't find it either.
How is it possible to obtain the `amsthm.sty` and thereafter installing it. So far I've been lucky enough to have the Package Manager doing all the fuss automatically for me.

Comment: I don't use MikTeX, but it's probably bundled with `amsmath` or some more general package with `ams` in the name, perhaps `ams-latex`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You probably have been bitten by the same problem exposed in this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96778/

Comment: Thank you! Though not the exact same problem, the thread helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 11):

The file `amsthm.sty` is part of MiKTeX's `amscls` package.  Using the MiKTeX Package Manager, you should install `amscls`.  You will probably want to install the `amsmath` package as well, for any mathematical typesetting.

In general, you can find out which MiKTeX package any file is in, by typing the full file name (such as in this case `amsthm.sty`) into the box at the top of the package manager labelled `File name:` and then clicking the `Filter` button.